# Separating an array into three

Tags: java, arrays, split

I currently have a 2d array, could anyone explain how i would extract the following:

the 0th to the 4th row the whole way down the array
then the 5th-10th row the whole way down the array
then the 11th-16th row the whole way down the array

I then want to hold these in 3 seperate arrays.

and then once I have carried out calculations on each individual array how do i sum them all back to one array?

This is the calculations I will carry out on the full array, that I would like to carry out on each individual array.

```
double[][] newjagssw = jaggedarr;
  for(int i=0; i<jaggedarr.length; i++){

        for(int j = 0; j<jaggedarr[i].length; j++){
            newjagssw[i][j] = jaggedarr[i][j] - average[i];
            double hold = newjagssw[i][j];
            newjagssw[i][j] = Math.pow(hold, 2);
        }
    }

    sst = new double[record]; 
    for(int i = 0; i < sst.length; i++){
        double hold = 0;
        for(int j= 0; j < newjagssw[i].length; j++){
            hold = hold + newjagssw[i][j];
        }
        sst[i] = hold;
        System.out.println(probename[i] + ": " + ssw[i]);
    }return ssw;
```

is there anyway of adapting it?

Thanks.

Comment: There are many ways to combine rows 0-4 into a single array (not code, but the result you want); which are you looking for?  (An example would be helpful.)

Comment: @ScottHunter thanks for a reply, the array that we are manipulating is jaggedarr? it would be helpful if we could keep it in code as we need to add these together after we carry out caluclations.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question (see my point about an example).