# How to extract rows and columns from arrays

Tags: java, arrays

can anyone please help me, I wanted to extract certain rows from a jag 2d array. I tried to do this. but it is not working and I got an error message:cannot find symbol - method substring(int,int). also how do I add the three arrays together after I had carried out some calculations.
 thank you

```
private double[] Groups(){
        for (int i=0; i<jag.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j<jag[i].length; j++){
                newfirstGroup = jag.substring(0,4);
                newsecondGroup= jag.substring(5,11);
                newthirdGroup= jag.substring(12,17);
            }
        }
        return newfirstGroup; 
        return newsecondGroup;
        return newthirdGroup;
    }
```

Comment: Which is the first line that contains `jag`? Why do you have 3 `return`s?

Comment: This code does not compile. Try again.

Comment: is `jag` a `double[][]`, or maybe a `string[][]`?

Comment: @SamIam , Hi there, I am not sure how to extract the information I need from my array, so thats my attempt. Sorry. Just learning Java. Essentially I am trying to get the 0th to 4th (first five) for every column, the 5th - 10th(next 6) from every column and 11th-16th(next 6th) from every column into separate arrays then I will carry out calculations on these, and then how do I sum these together?

Comment: @StudentMe where is `jag` declared?

Comment: @engineer , Hi, I have an array and three groups within a 2d array that holds 17 rows and 19 columns, but I need to work out separate the groups (number of records in each group 5,6,6)  to run a SSW anova calculation on them and then sum them. But do not know how to do this?

Comment: @SamIam it's  public double[][] jag;

Comment: @StudentMe do you know which row you want to extract?

Comment: Slightly better explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36945963/separating-an-array-into-three). It's a `double[][]` and he wants to get the columns contained in the rows `jag[0]` through `jag[4]`, `jag[5]` through `jag[11]`, and `jag[12]` through `jag[17]` grouped together as three separate arrays, process the data inside each subset, then put them back together.

Comment: @jonhopkins  Yes, that's how you extract a row from the jagged array.  `double[] row = jag[0]`  takes the 0th row of `jag` and puts it in a variable named `row`

Comment: @SamIam thats great, but will that only pull the 0th, how do I put the 0th row to the 4th row into one array. you are making sense to me, thank you

Comment: @SamIam I calculated SST and it worked   double[][] newjag = jag;

        for(int i=0; i<jag.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j<jag[i].length; j++){
                newjag[i][j] = jag[i][j] - average[i];
                double hold = newjag[i][j];
                newjag[i][j] = Math.pow(hold, 2);
            }
        }
 sst = new double[record]; 
        for(int i = 0; i < sst.length; i++){
            double hold = 0;
            for(int j= 0; j < newjag[i].length; j++){
                hold = hold + newjag[i][j];
            }
            sst[i] = hold;

Comment: `double[] row0 = jag[0];`, `double[] row1 = jag[1];` etc.

Comment: @SamIam thank you, how do I get that all for the columns in my jad array, ie the 19. thank you, you have been great help

Comment: `double col0 = row00[0];` `double col01 = row0[1];` etc.

Comment: @StudentMe you should also understand that things like `jag[0]` are expressions, and they don't have to be assigned to a brand new variable, so it's perfectly valid to do something like `System.out.println( jag[0][1])`

Comment: essentially, `double[][] jag` is an array that contains elements of type `double[]`

Comment: @SamIam I believe the intent here, rather than get each of the 17 rows by themselves, is to have something like `double[][] newfirstGroup = new double[5][19];` and fill it with the first five rows from `jag` and the same thing for the other two groups, then somehow return the three separate groups. Calculations will then be performed on those three separate groups of rows, and later stored back into the original `jag` array.

Comment: @jonhopkins  I understand that, but In order to do that, he needs to fundamentally understand how arrays are structured, and knowing that `jag[i]` results in a `double[]` when `jag` is a `double[][]`, is crucial, and it should be the first step.

Comment: @jonhopkins and furthermore, I think he wants something more like `double[][] newfirstGroup = new double[5][];` (I think that's the syntax, it's been so long since I've touched Java)

Comment: @SamIam fair enough. I figured you might just be breaking it down for that reason. But since there hasn't been much activity on this and the (essentially identical) post I linked to earlier, I figured it would be beneficial to get the intent out there in case anyone was confused (I will admit it took me a bit). And I'm not 100% sure on the syntax for 2d arrays in this kind of situation either, so I just went with the safer option there.

Answer (score 0):

First of all in a java method if a return statement is encountered it will come out of method , so your logic of three return statements wont work.

To return all three values create a Map and put all three arrays values and return map